# Can I get place details for an entire governorate at once as a JSON file or dataset & how much it'd cost me?

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

Can I get place details for an entire governorate at once as a JSON file or dataset from Google Maps official API, how much it'd cost me?

Comment: A place details request is only for a single place. Please see [documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/google-maps-type-script-sample-using-react-google-maps-api-library-j9o1y5?file=/src/index.tsx). And with regards to billing. See [Billing section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#places-details) from the documentation. And please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help from the community. :'>